# Launch an application in a different "context"

Tags: java, android, android-intent

First of all, sorry for the "context" in the question title, I didn't know which word to use. I successfully launch my app by clicking over a URL from another application, but when I launch the task manager I realize that my application is not actually loaded: the caller app holds the activities. I would like how to:

- Launch my app in a different "context" (sorry for the word again, which would be better?)
- Be able to reload my app in the case it was already loaded (something like restarting it).

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the behavior by setting "*launchMode*" attribute in *AndroidManifest.xml* to either "*singleTask*" or "*singleInstance*", both would cause your Activity to be created as the root of a new task. However it doesn't restart the Activity if it exist already, instead you should handle the `Activity.onNewIntent(Intent intent)` callback.

To learn more on launchMode see here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `launchMode` that Kai mentioned, you might also want to look at [`taskAffinity`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#aff) and [`allowTaskReparenting`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#reparent), depending on how your app is structured.

This is an excerpt from there that seems to match how you describe your app:

> For example, if an e-mail message contains a link to a web page, clicking the link brings up an activity that can display the page. That activity is defined by the browser application, but is launched as part of the e-mail task. If it's reparented to the browser task, it will be shown when the browser next comes to the front, and will be absent when the e-mail task again comes forward.